# Datepicker Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

If i were to import V4, there will be  error on fragment. However, there's no error on activity. However, if i were to import non-v4 version the fragment would be fine. However, the activity would not be working..

Thanks in advance!

PatientInfoFragment

```
public class PatientInfoFragment extends Fragment{

    DateDialogFragment frag;
    Button button;
    Calendar now;


    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    // DATABASE ADAPTOR
    patientDbAdapter patientDB;
    Context myContext;
    String ID = "0";

    // SPINNER AND SEARCH VIEW
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private TextView mStatusView;
    private Spinner locationSpinner;

    // DATE SPINNER
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    private TextView mDateDisplay;
    static final int DIALOG_ALERT = 1;

    // declaration
    private EditText patientInitial, dateOfDiagnosis, wardClinic;
    private Spinner locSpinner;
    private CheckBox history, physical;
    private String siteLocation;
    String patientKey = "com.example.app.datetime";
    // Verification
    Boolean fromBase = false;

    //Data From PatientDetails 
    String strValue1 ;
    String strValue2 ; 
    String strValue3 ;
    String strValue4 ;
    String strValue5 ;
    String strValue6 ;
    private String patientID;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    View rootView;

    public PatientInfoFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_patient_info,
                container, false);

            history = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_history);
            physical = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_physical);
            patientInitial = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.InitialTextEdit);
            locSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.locationSpinner);
            dateOfDiagnosis = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showMyDate);
            siteLocation = locSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            wardClinic = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.WardClinicTextEdit);

            // listener for the Ward/ClinicSpinner
            addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
//      DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();

    //    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    private void RetrieveDataFromDatabaseBasedOnID(String paramString) {
        myContext = getActivity();
        // Opening of database
        patientDB = new patientDbAdapter(myContext);
        patientDB.open();

        ID = paramString;
        Cursor mCursor = this.patientDB
                .retrievePatientEntriesBasedOnID(paramString);
        if ((mCursor != null) && (mCursor.getCount() > 0)) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();

            mCursor.getString(0); // ID
            this.strValue1 = mCursor.getString(1); // Initial
            this.strValue2 = mCursor.getString(2);// Date
            this.strValue3 = mCursor.getString(3);// SiteLocation
            this.strValue4 = mCursor.getString(4);// WardClinic
            this.strValue5 = mCursor.getString(5);// CheckBoxHistory
            this.strValue6 = mCursor.getString(6);// CheckBoxPhysical

            patientInitial = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.InitialTextEdit);
            locSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.locationSpinner);
            dateOfDiagnosis = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showMyDate);
            siteLocation = locSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            wardClinic = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.WardClinicTextEdit);
            history = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_history);
            physical = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_physical);

            patientInitial.setText(strValue1);
            dateOfDiagnosis.setText(strValue2);
    //      ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    //              R.array.location_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        //  int S = adapter.getPosition(strValue3);

        //  locSpinner.setSelection(S);
            wardClinic.setText(strValue4);
            if (strValue5.equals("Y")) {
                history.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (strValue6.equals("Y")) {
                physical.setChecked(true);
            }
            fromBase = true;
        } else {
            fromBase = false;
        }
    }

    // Listen to the spinner Item Selection - Completed
    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        locationSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.locationSpinner);
        // locationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new
        // CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    }

    // Listen to the spinner
    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        // retrieveValue
        locationSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.locationSpinner);
    }

    public void openPatientSearch() {
        Intent patientDetailsIntent = new Intent(myContext, PatientDetails.class);
        //StartActivityForResult doesn't work for fragment
    //  PatientInfo.this.startActivityForResult(patientDetailsIntent, 1);
    }


    public void showDialog() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); //get the fragment
        frag = DateDialogFragment.newInstance(getActivity(), new DateDialogFragmentListener(){
            public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day){
                button.setText(String.valueOf(month+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(day)+"-"+String.valueOf(year));
                now.set(year, month, day);
            }
        }, now);

        frag.show(ft, "DateDialogFragment");

    }

    public interface DateDialogFragmentListener{
        //this interface is a listener between the Date Dialog fragment and the activity to update the buttons date
        public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day);
    }




}
```

DatePickerFragment

```
    package com.medilearner.fragment;


import java.util.Calendar;

import com.medilearner.fragment.DatePickerActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class DateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static String TAG = "DateDialogFragment";
    static Context mContext; //I guess hold the context that called it. Needed when making a DatePickerDialog. I guess its needed when conncting the fragment with the context
    static int mYear;
    static int mMonth;
    static int mDay;
    static DateDialogFragmentListener mListener;

    public static DateDialogFragment newInstance(Context context, DateDialogFragmentListener listener, Calendar now) {
        DateDialogFragment dialog = new DateDialogFragment();
        mContext = context;
        mListener = listener;

        mYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        /*I dont really see the purpose of the below*/
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", "Set Date");
        dialog.setArguments(args);//setArguments can only be called before fragment is attached to an activity, so right after the fragment is created


        return dialog;
    }


    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(mContext, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }


    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;

            mListener.updateChangedDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: import same fragment class in both. What is the error?